# R Only extract 3 digit numbers from a string

Tags: r, string, gsub

I have the following data

```
data <- data.frame(make=c("af455f5","255tfd4d3","ojt100","12unin234mimo24","sh469dh","6ht6k778k9","kjh457"),
               type=c("a","a","a","a","b","a","b"))
```

I only want to extract any three digit numbers from the "make" elements if the corresponding type is "a".

I've tried using gsub but can only seem to extract all the numbers in a combined string.

the result I'm looking for is as follows

```
result <- c("455","255","100","234","778")
```

Answer (score 4):

This looks like it does what you want.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(data$make,"[0-9]{3}")[data$type=="a"]
```

Result:

```
[1] "455" "255" "100" "234" "778"
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

We can use `base R` methods for this

```
v1 <- data$make[data$type == "a"]
regmatches(v1, regexpr("[0-9]{3}", v1))
#[1] "455" "255" "100" "234" "778"
```

---

Or with `sub`

```
sub("^.*([0-9]{3}).*", "\\1", v1)
#[1] "455" "255" "100" "234" "778"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer:

```
library(stringr)

str_extract(data$make[data$type == 'a'], '[0-9]{3}')

## "455" "255" "100" "234" "778"
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be achieved using the `strapplyc` from `gsubfn` package:

```
result <- sapply(as.character(df$make[df$type=='a']), 
             function(x) strapplyc(x, "\\d{3}", simplify = TRUE))
```

output:

```
result
# af455f5       255tfd4d3          ojt100 12unin234mimo24      6ht6k778k9 
# "455"           "255"           "100"           "234"           "778"
```